# Looking for an example of software (or code) that can render a window "over" (z-order) system menus

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I'm using Talon accessibility software which magnifies an area of the screen based on eye-tracking.  Usually, the magnified area will appear "on top" (covering) the "normal window", but this doesn't work with "system menus" such as:

- Calendar menu
- Power-off/Log-out menu
- Window control menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

These menus cover the screen magnifier, rather than the other way around.

It looks like this:

[image: Screen shot of a menu]

I've asked the Talon developers about this.  Apparently it is using the "topmost" window flag, but for some reason it doesn't work in the case of system menus.  The developer has asked if there's any example of other software that can render a window "above" (z-order) a system menu, so that it might be used as a guide for how to implement it in Talon.

Is anyone aware of software that can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Unfortunately it's very difficult to understand your question.  I *think* you are saying that there is some type of issue with Talon displaying its user interface when there is a system menu on the screen, but I'm not quite sure.  If there's any way for you to add a screenshot of the issue, that might help people provide suggestions.  Also, have you asked about this in the [Talon Slack](https://talonvoice.com/chat)?

Comment: I updated the question. Yes I asked about this in Slack, the developer said that if I could provide an example of software that renders on top of this menus he can take a look at what they're doing differently.

Comment: Thanks - I believe the screenshot helped.  I've made an attempt to clarify the wording of the question, since a few other reviewers found it to be unclear.  Let me know if I'm representing your question accurately.  Feel free to edit again if needed, of course.  Thanks!